# Avoiding namespace prefixes with Saxon XPath against XHTML

Tags: xpath, namespaces, xhtml, saxon, jaxp

Using Saxon HE 9.6 as a JAXP implementation

Have an HTML document with the XHTML namespace

`//*:title` returns the expected value, but `//title` doesn't

I'd really like to just use `//title`. How can this be done?

Alternatively, can I just remove a namespace from an already constructed Document?

Comment: Seriously, don't. XPath uses prefixes to bind namespaces. Get used to using them.

Comment: @Alohci using HTMLUnit, which uses Apache for XPath, and doesn't use namespaces. So all my XPaths already have no namespaces. Want to upgrade to XPath 2.0, but not re-write all my well-tested queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/1649, you can cast the JAXP `XPath` object you have created from a Saxon XPathFactory implementation to a `net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator` and then set the default XPath namespace for XPath evaluation with e.g.

```
((XPathEvaluator)xpath).getStaticContext().setDefaultElementNamespace("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

Then a path `//title` will select `title` elements in the XHTML namespace. I tested that to work in a sample

```
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = new XPathFactoryImpl();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
    ((XPathEvaluator)xpath).getStaticContext().setDefaultElementNamespace("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");


    String xhtmlSample = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><title>This is a test</title></head><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>";
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xhtmlSample));

    System.out.println("Found: " + xpath.evaluate("//title", source));
```